# ios 9, xcode 7 different behaviour when attached or not

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am migrating my app from ios 8 to ios 9 and I have found something strange, or at least it is the first time it happens to me and I have found no similar case.

I work with xcode 7 and ios 9. When I launch the app in an iphone 6 attached to xcode everything goes fine.

But if I do the same without attaching the app to xcode, it doesn't connect to my web service. The only difference is the iphone being attached to xcode or not.

I know I'm not giving much informatio, but any hint you could give me would be of great help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, to make your web services work, you need add one setting in your **info.plist**, see image below

[image]

For your ease the settings is

> ```
> NSAppTransportSecurity -> Dictionary
>       NSAllowsArbitraryLoads -> Boolean -> YES
> ```

**Reference**
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/

Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!